# Login by Google secured by Context-Aware Access?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

Currently, Context-Aware Access can restrict access to:

- Google Workspace Apps
- service with IAP enables
- GCP resources

Is it possible to restrict to use of a corporate account to any OAuth login?
For example, I want to prohibit using login by google (with corporate account) on external sites not connected with our company.

Probably it isn't possible for now. Does anyone know if this functionality is on the Context-Aware Access road map?

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of the [admin console](https://admin.google.com). Go to Apps and here you can add the whitelisted and the blacklisted app.